# Static array elements in modern Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95, fortran2003, fortran2008

For convenience I would like to be able to reference elements of a static look up table implemented as a 1d array like this

```
Item = [1,7,2,5,3](I)
```

Where I is an integer index to the static array in the square brackets. I know I can declare a named array and use that, but I’m wondering if there’s an appropriate syntax for the above intent.

Comment: *Fuggeddaaboutit*, there's no Fortran syntax close to that.  The approach you know you can use is the approach to use, not forgetting that the static array can be declared to be a `parameter`.  It's not clear to me why you would want to use the 'array literal' in multiple locations when you could declare it once and use it many times - it would be a *magic array*.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll stop looking. Yes the static array parameter is what I will do.  This (honestly!) is only to be used in one place so I’d rather have the literal values where they are used than in another part of the code.

Comment: The linked question is about array function results, but it's really much the same concept for array expressions.  As High Performance Mark says, there's no syntax even close, so you'll need do something like the wrapping mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: *I’d rather have the literal values where they are used* You may be able to take advantage of the screamingly modern `block` construct to declare the array near to its only use if that appeals.  Or possibly `associate`.

Comment: Thanks High Performance Mark.  Nice idea - unfortunately my compiler is not quite screamingly modern enough. I appreciate the suggestions.